# How To Remove CSS Filter From Child Class?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am new to CSS and I was looking at this beautiful code:

https://jsfiddle.net/heckz72g/

The problem here is that I have defined font "color" as "blue", yet the filter comes upon the text and it is no more blue. It changes according to the filter applied. How do I make the text color blue only?

This is the out put of fiddle:

[image: This is What I am getting]

This is what I want:

[image]

Please tell me how to remove the css-filter on the text ("SOME TEXT") and make all the text color "blue"?

HTML:

```
<div class="button-wrapper">

  <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 25.92%;
  display: block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  font-family: 'luckiest guy';
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a.background-button {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/323909/yellow-shadow.png);
}
a.background-button:after {
  content: attr(title);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/323909/yellow-top.png);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
a.background-button:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(2.5%, 10%);
  transform: translate(2.5%, 10%);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px white;
  color: black;
}
.button-wrapper {
  width: 355px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(2) a {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(36deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(36deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(3) a {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(72deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(72deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(108deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(108deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(144deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(144deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(252deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(252deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(288deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(288deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(324deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(324deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete all of this:

```
.button-wrapper:nth-child(2) a {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(36deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(36deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(3) a {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(72deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(72deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(108deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(108deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(144deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(144deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(252deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(252deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(288deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(288deg);
}
.button-wrapper:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(324deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(324deg);
}
```

You can control the color of the text from:

```
a {
   color: red;
}
```

I would suggest you not to use background-image if you want to change its color.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i tried this, but I want the background image. I tried everything but could not replicate it. So i need both the picture and filter, but filter should not be on the text.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Check it will work

```css
        body {
          text-align: center;
        }
        a {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          padding-top: 25.92%;
          display: block;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
          font-family: 'luckiest guy';
          font-size: 28px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        .background-button {
          background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/323909/yellow-shadow.png);
        }
        .background-button:after {
          content: attr(title);
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          display: block;
          background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/323909/yellow-top.png);
          transition: all 0.3s;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }
        .background-button:hover:after {
          -webkit-transform: translate(2.5%, 10%);
          transform: translate(2.5%, 10%);
          text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px white;
        }
        .button-wrapper {
          width: 355px;
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 20px;
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(2) a {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(36deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(36deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(3) a {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(72deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(72deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(4) {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(108deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(108deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(5) {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(144deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(144deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(6) {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(7) {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(8) {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(216deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(9) {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(252deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(252deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(7) {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(288deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(288deg);
        }
        .button-wrapper:nth-child(8) {
          -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(324deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(324deg);
        }
```

```html
        <div class="button-wrapper">

          <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <a class="background-button" href="#" title="SOME TEXT"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, i am sorry if i could not explain it clearly. The code is working fine. I want those hue filter on every element to color the boxes, but not on the text color. You can try this by changing the font color. When you change it to any non black or white character, the hue filter gets applied on the text color and so all the text colors look different.

Comment: Ok but please try to define your problem in simple way then it will be solved.

Comment: Hello. Pease check the post again. I hope my question is now clear.

Comment: Thanks @Rohan i now edited my answer please check my answer again..

Comment: I just ran the code on fiddle and unfortunately the text color is not blue. Here is the fiddle of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/bxheg7tw/

Comment: it depend on your environment but in snippet it will work right.